# How can I select multiple rows, all having a same id (or any variable) within a database using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table looks like this:

```
id  user    rollnumber  start       end         reason    aprroved
1   john    123456      04/04/2015  04/15/2015  Visit     NULL
2   john    notyet      04/01/2015  04/29/2015  personal  NULL
3   tony    notyet      04/15/2015  04/29/2015  Visit     NULL
4   tony    9635241     04/08/2015  04/29/2015  personal  NULL
```

I have to print all the rows having user equals to john in php. So in this case, what mysql query should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple If I understood you only need to use `WHERE` clause. You can read [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) about `SELECT` syntax.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE [user] = 'john'
```